# RouteValues and ActionLink, Pass Data to other action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

passing some parameters in `Html.ActionLink` with QueryString Is Possible . but when using `RedirectToAction` how pass parameters . it just accept route value , i want to add ReturnValue Parameter to destination action that after action executed return to that like Login Mechanism , but how pass with `RedirectToAction`?

Comment: possible duplicate with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209191/how-do-i-include-a-model-with-a-redirecttoaction)

Comment: What Is Different Between `RoutValue` And `Query String` ? visit the Answer

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to add axtension Method to that like this

```
public static class RedirectToRouteExtensions
    {
        public static RedirectToRouteResult WithQuery(this RedirectToRouteResult redirectResult, string name, string val)
        {
            redirectResult.RouteValues.Add(name, val);
            return redirectResult;
        }
        public static RedirectToRouteResult And(this RedirectToRouteResult redirectResult, string name, string val)
        {
            return redirectResult.WithQuery(name, val);
        }
}
```

and use this :

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Profile", new { area = "Customer").WithQuery("name", "Value");
```

using route Values and QueryString Do Same , So What is Different Between Them?

Answer (score 0):

Any parameters that the destination action method requires can just be passed in the route values, e.g.

```
return RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller", new { returnValue = "returnValue" });
```