# Wrong list pasted via RedirectToAction method in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I faced the following error while using the `RedirectToAction` method in ASP.NET MVC 5.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadOrderReport(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        string targetFolder = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Reports");
        string targetPath = Path.Combine(targetFolder, file.FileName);
        file.SaveAs(targetPath);

        var currentReports = Directory.GetFiles(targetFolder).ToList();
        return RedirectToAction("CurrentProfile", new { existReport = new List<string>(currentFiles)});
    }
```

However, in my `CurrentProfile` method I got unexpected data

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(List<string> existReports)
```

and debugger shows that `existsReports` argument is ``` System.Collections.Generic.List``1[System.String] ```

I suppose my problem related to type casting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RedirectToAction` method is going to return a 302 response to your browser with the new url as the location header value. The browser will make a new HTTP request to this new url.

If you look at the RedirectToAction method overloads, you can see that the third parameter is for routevalues(which will for the querystring values)

```
protected internal RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToAction(
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    object routeValues
)
```

You should not be passing complex data(like a list of items) to the `RedirectToAction` method. Basically, when you pass some small objects,it will be converted to the querystring values.

If you want to pass a complex data, i suggest you to pass a uniqueId from which the list can be retrieved in your GET action again. If that is not an option, consider using TempData.

**Passing a unique id**

```
return RedirectToAction("CurrentProfile",new { listId="someUniqueIdHere"});
```

This will set the location header value as `/YourController/CurrentProfile?listId=someUniqueIdHere`

**Passing via TempData**

```
TempData["existReport "] = new List<string>(currentFiles);
return RedirectToAction("CurrentProfile", "yourControllerName");
```

And read it in your `CurrentProfile` GET Action method again.

```
public ActionResult CurrentProfile()
{      
  var items=TempData["existReport"] as List<string>
  return View(model);
}
```

Take a look at [How do I include a model with a RedirectToAction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209191/how-do-i-include-a-model-with-a-redirecttoaction) as well