# How can i change the url after form post

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
var url = 'http://localhost:55026/Home/getData';
var hiddendata = $("<input>").attr("name","snippet").attr('value',"content").attr('type', 'hidden')
var form = $('<form action="' + url + '" method="post" target="_blank" >'  + '</form>');
$(form).append(hiddendata);
$('body').append(form);
form.submit();


[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult getData(string snippet)
{
}
```

After getting value from controller i need to change the url like `http://localhost:55026`instead of `http://localhost:55026/Home/getData`;

Is this possible?

Comment: perform a redirect.

Comment: Thanks for your response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the `RedirectToAction` method in your HttpPost action method.

```
[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult getData(string snippet)
{
   //to do : Do something with posted data
   return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
}
```

This will send a 302 response to the browser with the location header value as `/Home/Index` and the browser will make a new GET request to this location.

Assuming `Home/Index` is your default action as per the routing configuration.

If you want to show the data in `Home/Index`, [you may pass it using querystring /TempData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209191/how-do-i-include-a-model-with-a-redirecttoaction)

**With Querystring**

```
return RedirectToAction("Index","Home",new {id=snippet});
```

Now in your index action, add a parameter called id and you can read the value there

```
public ActionResult Index(string id="")
{
  //check the value in id param. you may pass to your view as needed
}
```

**With TempData**

```
TempData["Snippet"] = snippet;
return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
```

Now in your index action

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var id=TempData["Snippet"] as string;
  //check the value in id variable. you may pass to your view as needed
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.Here i can't pass the data to view  public ActionResult getData(string snippet)
{return View("Index");} .I have tried as per your suggestion.but i can't pass the value to view.it diredctly redirected to 'http://localhost:55026'

Comment: Your initial question was how to do the redirect, If you want to show the data, you need to do `return View()` and pass the data to the view as needed. The url is going to be `/Home/getData`. If you want the url to be just `yourSiteName`, you may consider replacing `getData` method with the `Index` action of `Home` controller. With the default routing configuration the url `yourSiteName`(without any controller/action) will be handled by `Home/Index`

Comment: Thanks for your response

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
Response.Redirect("~/");
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Comment: Sure.this is helped for redirect the link.but Here i can't pass the form data to view .please refer my code.public ActionResult getData(string snippet) {return View("Index");} .I have tried as per your suggestion.but i can't pass the value to view.it diredctly redirected to 'localhost:55026';

Comment: If it is a simple string or int value, you can store in Tempdata and access the same in the View?

Comment: Thanks for your response