# Pass created data to another controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using ASP.NET MVC Entity Framework and I have a page to insert data

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: /Home/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="id,firstname,lastname,email,guests,guestfirstname,guestlastname,productInterest,occupancyTimeline,isInvestment,timeSlot,dateSlot")] CP_LC_Preview cp_lc_preview)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Data.Add(cp_lc_preview);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Confirm", new { info = cp_lc_preview });
            }

            return View(cp_lc_preview);
        }
```

What I am trying to do is take that data that was just entered and pass it to another controller to display. like a confirmation page.

Here is my method for the confirm page

```
public ActionResult Confirm()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: "pass it" from where?  Generally a controller action would accept a model as a method parameter, as you've already done in the second `Create()` method.  How specifically is the user requesting the `Confirm()` action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may consider following the **PRG** pattern.

**PRG** stands for **POST - REDIRECT - GET**. With this approach,After you successfully save the data, you will issue a redirect response with a unique id in the querystring, using which the second GET action method can query the resource again and return something to the view.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="id,firstname,lastname,email,guests,guestfirstname,guestlastname,productInterest,occupancyTimeline,isInvestment,timeSlot,dateSlot")] CP_LC_Preview cp_lc_preview)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       db.Data.Add(cp_lc_preview);
       db.SaveChanges();
       var id = cp_lc_preview.Id; 
       return RedirectToAction("Confirm", new { id = id });
    }
   return View(cp_lc_preview);
}
```

and in your Confirm action method, have id parameter and using the value of that read the record from the db again and use as needed.

```
public ActionResult Confirm(int id)
{
   var d = db.Data.FirstOrDefault(g=>g.Id==id);
   // Use d as needed   
   // to do : Return something
}
```

**TempData**

If you do not prefer to have this id in the url, consider using `TempData` to pass the data. But TempData has a short life span. Once read, the data is gone. TempData uses Session behind the scene to store the data.

```
TempData["NewItem"] = cp_lc_preview;
return RedirectToAction("Confirm", "controllerName");
```

and in the Confirm method

```
public ActionResult actionname()
{      
  var model=TempData["NewItem"] as CP_LC_Preview 
  // to do : Return something
}
```

For your reference

[How do I include a model with a RedirectToAction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209191/how-do-i-include-a-model-with-a-redirecttoaction)

Answer (score 2):

You can use **TempData** for that.

```
TempData["YourData"] = YourData;//persist data for next request

var myModel=TempData["YourData"] as YourData //consume it  on the next request
```

**What is TempData ?**

> 1. TempData is meant to be a very short-lived instance, and you should only use it
>    during the current and the subsequent requests only.
> 2. Since TempData works this way, you need to know for sure what the next request will be, and
>    redirecting to another view is the only time you can guarantee this.
> 3. Therefore, the only scenario where using TempData will reliably work is when
>    you are redirecting.This is because a redirect kills the current request , then creates a
>    new request on the server to serve the redirected view.
> 4. Simply said, Asp.Net MVC TempData dictionary is used to share data between
>    controller actions.
> 5. The value of TempData persists until it is read or until the current user’s session times out.
> 6. By default, the TempData saves its content to the session state.
> 7. TempData values are marked for deletion when you read them. At the end of the request,
>    any marked values are deleted.
> 8. The benefit is that if you have a chain of multiple redirections it won’t cause TempData to
>    be emptied the values will still be there until you actually use them, then they clear up after
>    themselves automatically.