# Passed uploaded-image to a another controller not showing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form with one image-upload and a Submit button..

When i press the submit button, I can read the uploaded-image info in my controller (see image 1 )

The problem is, when i from this controller pass the uploaded-image info to another controller, see image 2

The "another" controller dont get the image info, its HttpPostedFileBase is null / 0

Why does it do that, what can I do ?

```
[HttpPost]
[UserAuthorize(Roles = "User")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult NewProject(NewUserProjectViewModel model)
{
        return RedirectToAction("previewProject", model);
}


[UserAuthorize(Roles = "User")]
public ActionResult previewProject(NewUserProjectViewModel model)
{
    return View(model);
}
```

[IMAGE 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeYOA.png)
[IMAGE 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iES8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RedirectToAction actually sends a 302 response to the browser with the new url as the location header value and the browser will read this response and issue a totally new GET request to the new url. You cannot pass a complex model with RedirectToAction.

You have few options

1. You can directly call the `PreviewProject` view from your `NewProject` action method and pass the object.

   ```
   public ActionResult NewProject(NewUserProjectViewModel model)
   {
      return View("previewProject", model);
   }
   ```
2. You can persist the model data and pass a unique id to the next action method when you send a RedirectResult response. In the second action method, use a parameter for this unique id and using which you can get the data again and use that.

   ```
   public ActionResult NewProject(NewUserProjectViewModel model)
   {
      var id = SaveModelAndReturnUniqueID(model);
      return RedirectToAction("previewProject", new {id=id});
   }
   public ActionResult previewProject(int id)
   {
      NewUserProjectViewModel model= GetNewUserProjectViewModel(id);
      return View(model);
   }
   ```
3. Use a temporary persisting mechanism like Session or TempData.

Take a look at [How do I include a model with a RedirectToAction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209191/how-do-i-include-a-model-with-a-redirecttoaction/11209320#11209320)