# How to update/edit record Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm having this issue where I'm unable to update a data. It will go to the edit page but when I click update it just redirects to the other page and there's no data shown. How can get the updated data to be shown when it is redirected. Update question with class issue

controller:

```
 private Issue getIssue
    {
        get
        {
            Issue issue = (Issue)Session["Issue"];
            if (issue == null)
            {
                issue = new Issue();
                Session["Issue"] = issue;
            }
            return issue;

        }

    }


    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {

        getIssue.item = getIssue.items[id - 1];//Returns the requested item for editing
        return View(getIssue);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Issue issue)
    {
        int indx = issue.item.lineNum - 1;
        getIssue.items[indx] = issue.item;
        //return View(getIssue);
        return RedirectToAction("IssueItem", "Issue");
   }
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Issue</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })



    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-horizontal">

            <hr />
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.item.itemNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.item.itemNumber, null, new { @id = "itemNumber", @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly", })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.item.itemNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.item.description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.item.description, null, new { @id = "description", @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly", })
                    @*  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.item.description, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2", @id = "txtItem" })*@
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.item.description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>


<div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Update" name="Update" class="btn btn-default" />
                    <input type="button" value="Cancel" name="Cancel" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("IssueItem","Issue")' " class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>

            </div>
```

Comment: you didnt provide the update button on the code above.

Comment: yes it is there  <input type="submit" value="Update" name="Update" class="btn btn-default" />

Comment: Follow the [P-R-G pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209191/how-do-i-include-a-model-with-a-redirecttoaction/11209320#11209320).

Comment: something like this     return RedirectToAction("IssueItem", "Issue", new { indx = getIssue.items[indx] });

Comment: Post the code of your class Issue

Comment: @shyju so I have added this  return RedirectToAction("IssueItem", "Issue", new { id = indx }); but when it returns the data is not shown

Comment: Is your IssueItem action method reading the data based on the id passed to it ?

Comment: this is the url that is returned localhost:50616/Issue/IssueItem/0

Comment: @Shyju;could you tell me what else I'm missing the data not to be returning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I'm using a session to clear out the fields so each time it redirects that session was cleared out; I've since remove and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `getIssue.items[indx] = issue.item;` updates the item,

After updating a item the server must:

1. Know what item was update
2. Redirect the user to the updated item.

The redirect `RedirectToAction("IssueItem", "Issue");` is redirecting to a generc URL, not a specific one. That is the problem.

1. Lets get what item was updated. You don't use Id but you do use `indx` on the `[HttpPost]` method. so we know that `indx` has the identification number of the item.
2. Lets redirect the user to the item page. I don't know your project, so I will assume that there is a `Detail` page. We get the `indx` variable and pass it as arg to the `redirect`:  for instance `RedirectToAction("Detail",new {id = indx});`  This should work.

Comment: could you give a snippet because id is not apart of the  Edit(Issue issue) so that variable would give an error

Comment: I changed the answer, you are using `indx` instead of id

Comment: ok so when it returns it doesn't show the data and this in the url localhost:50616/Issue/IssueItem/0

Comment: Hey @Daniel I'm stuck as to how to get the updated on the page

Comment: the issue is still there once i click update it goes back without the data

Comment: Hey Daniel do you have time to look on this issue for me please. I'm still having the issue when it redirects it doesn't show the updated data

Comment: The data isn’t shown outdated? Or no data is shown.?

Comment: I’m sorry. I need much more details to understand what is going wrong with your application. At this point I strongly advise you to try to understand how this app works and maybe take a small asp.net mvc course. You will find very good ones .

Comment: I understand how it works, but just the part that the data is being "erased" once I return

Comment: Is it possible for you to show me a snippet of what would happen when it returns

Comment: Hey @Daniel is it possible to give me some assistance on this question, after I thought i have figured out this problem, I'm getting an index error [id - 1] as id returns 0. How can I fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

First thing I noticed is that you are not saving the identifier of your object to be updated in the view, you should use Html.HiddenFor, like this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.lineNum)
```

I assumed that lineNum is the identifier of your object.

Comment: I'm having an issue relating to this question, I now realized that  the identifier object returns 0 and gives me an error. Question, can use something else instead of using line Num to identify the object. Cause on some occasions it only picks up the first item as id is always one

Comment: @TroyBrown I think you can also use the index of the element in your list. Or you can use a hash code, like: var hash = myObject.GetHashCode();

Comment: how would I use the index element in my list.