# Passing a ViewModel Between Controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to pass a `ViewModel` from one `Controller` to another. The `ViewModel` is created correctly initially but when it is passed to the next `Controller` it is null. Here is how the `ViewModel` is created:

**Login.cshtml**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <form action="/Login/LoginValidation" method="post">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" type="email" name="Email">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></span>
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" type="password" name="CorePassword">
        </div>
        <button class="btn-login" type="submit" value="Submit">Sign In</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**LoginController**

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost] // Only call this if HttpPost is used
    public IActionResult LoginValidation(Users user)
    {
        if (user != null)
        {
            if (LoginCheck(user))
            {
                var vm = new LoginViewModel
                {
                    User = user
                };
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", vm);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model BootstrapProgram.ViewModels.LoginViewModel

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hi there @Model.User.Email!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**HomeController**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index(LoginViewModel vm)
    {
        return View(vm);
    }
}
```

So as I said the `LoginViewModel` is created with the properties I would expect, however when it is passed into the `HomeController` and processed in `Index.cshtml` I get an error stating that the `@Model.User.Email` is null.

Comment: Your cannot pass objects that contain properties which are complex objects or collections using `RedirectToAction()`. Just pass the ID of the object and get it again in the `HomeController` method

Comment: @StephenMuecke is there anyway to pass complex objects (`ViewModels`?) or is this simply just not the thing to do in ASP.NET?

Comment: Are you okay with using `TempData`?

Comment: You can only do it if the model contains simple properties (and even then you get a ugly query string and risk exceeding the query string limit and throwing an exception). Just pass the ID of the object, although its unclear why your doing this.

Comment: @StephenMuecke - say for example someone logs in as a user, and on the next page I want to display a message saying "Hello LoggedInUser", should I pass the user ID?

Comment: Yes, or just the value of `Email` - e.g. `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { email = user.Email);` to `public IActionResult Index(string email)` if thats the only property you need to pass to the `Index.cshtml` view

Comment: Read this excellent answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209191/how-do-i-include-a-model-with-a-redirecttoaction