# Pass js complex array to mvc controller, and then return another view

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is related to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47232409/pass-js-array-to-mvc-controller-and-then-return-another-view).
I'm wondering, can I pass a JS array the same way (as the accepted answer in previous question) even if now I'm trying to send a bit more complex array:
[image]

If yes, then how? Getting nulls while receiving in controller.
this is my model:

```
public class QuestionModel
{
    public bool Choice { get; set; }
    public List<object> ChoiceQuestions { get; set; } //can i use List<object>?
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public bool Short { get; set; }
    public object ShortQuestion { get; set; } //here aswell - can I use object?
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Not even sure if I can reuse the js code for sending the data to controller that was given in the answer. If no, then how should I solve this? Still I have to be able to send the data via post to controller, and then after processing data return it back to the view.

Comment: How are you sending it ? You can post a complex object via ajax and the response of your action method(could be a view result) will come back to the success handler of the ajax call. If you want to navigate to a different page,ajax might not be the right solution here. Do a normal form post.

Comment: If it is an `object`, you (or the MVC binder) cannot set any properties. Maybe `dynamic` works, or create a real class for those questions.

Comment: Are you posting this as a normal submit or using ajax. If a normal submit, then you cannot use an array. You must use the correct names with collection indexers, for example if the POST methid is `List<QuestionModel>`, then your would need `[0].Choice: true`, `[0].ChoiceQuestions[0].Id: 0` etc

Comment: Its not clear why your building a JavaScript array of objects if your wanting to do a normal submit and redirect - you do not need to do that, or any javascript at all) if you have generated your view correctly in the first place

Comment: And do not use `object` - it should be `public List<ChoiceQuestionsVM> ChoiceQuestions` where `ChoiceQuestionsVM` is a class containing properties `Id` and `Value` (ditto for `public object ShortQuestion`)

Comment: Shyju, yes ajax is not the solution here.
@StephenMuecke Hmm... will normal submit work here? I will probably have up to even 50 of these complex arrays (as in the image). I'm building a JS array because it was easier for me to handle all the values of the array from many fields.

Comment: If you have generated you view correctly, then yes a normal submit will work. For example refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943) for how to generate form controls for models which are a collection (or models containing properties which are collections). Or if your dynamically adding collection items in a view, refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308)

Comment: Thanks I will have a look on that.

Answer (score 0):

You may make Json of any object as a single hidden form field and then **post** the form to action with string parameter. Then on server side desterilize json to the object inside the action method - even in another controller.  You may return different view from the controller method.

**Javascript** (Say on Stock Page/View)

```
var form = document.createElement("form");
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.setAttribute("type", "hidden") ;
input.setAttribute("name", "outwardStocks") ;
input.setAttribute("value", JSON.stringify(selectedrecords));
form.appendChild(input);
document.body.appendChild(form);
form.action = "/CRM/Invoice/Index";
form.method = "post"
form.submit();
```

**Controller code**  (Say Invoice Controller)

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(string outwardStocks)
{
   InvoiceItems invItems = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<InvoiceItems>(outwardStocks);
   ......
   return View("Invoice" InvoiceVM);
}
```