# return RedirectToAction does not pass route values

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

In my Index action I am checking for the presence of a request parameter and redirecting to a different action if it exists. The redirection is working, but it is not passing my route value object

```
// GET: Forecast
public ActionResult Index(FilterVm form)
{
    if (Request.Params["ExcelExport"] != null) // Return Excel File
        return RedirectToAction("ExcelExport", new { filter = form });
    else
    {
        // stuff omitted... 
        return View(vm);
    }
}
```

The action I am redirecting to:

```
// GET: Forecast/ExcelExport
public ActionResult ExcelExport(FilterVm filter)
{
    var dto = Mapper.Map<ForecastFilterDto>(filter);
    var excelFile = forecastService.GetForecastExcelExport(dto);
    string fileName = "EXCEL.xlsx";
    return File(excelFile.GetAsByteArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", fileName);
}
```

I noticed that when it hits the second "ExcelExport" action, the thread id also changes. I'm a relative noobie so I am not quite sure what is happening that could cause that.

I tried rolling both these actions into the Index action with an IF statement checking the parameter and returning the file if the parameter is present, and returning the view if not. When debugging that setup I noticed it returns the File, then continues on to return the view! I am at a complete loss as to what is going on here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I include a model with a RedirectToAction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209191/how-do-i-include-a-model-with-a-redirecttoaction)

Comment: Just `return RedirectToAction("ExcelExport", form);` - but it will only work if `FilterVm` contains simple properties (properties that are collections or complex objects will not be passed)

Comment: I'm curious to learn more about the "simple properties" statement. I did notice that my redirecttoaction will pass a primitive, just not my object. Why though, if I am able to bind to that object on the first request, could I not bind to that object on action I hit after the redirect?