# Is it possible to RedirectToAction and pass data to a HttpPost Action method? (ASP.NET Core)

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a large form that I've broken down into three smaller views. I want to detect with the user has already filled one step or more and redirect him accordingly. I am just trying to figure out a good solution for this. The user will be submiting data using the POST method from step to step - posting because I don't want that data be visible on the user URL (GET). The problem is that when there's session data telling that the user filled some step I want to post to the next step "programmatically", in the controlller, but I don't know how to do it.

This doesn't pass data...

```
  return RedirectToAction("PostDadosContato", new { dadosPessoais = dadosPessoais,  precompletado = true });
```

to this.

```
    public IActionResult PostDadosContato(DadosPessoais dadosPessoais, bool precompletado = false)
    {
    }
```

See in this picture.

[image]

Comment: Post code, not images

Comment: Redirect will make the browser to issue a new GET request. What is the point of redirecting to a POST method ? Take a look at this [How do I include a model with a RedirectToAction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209191/how-do-i-include-a-model-with-a-redirecttoaction/11209320#11209320)

Comment: If I cannot redirect to a POST method I don't know what to do. If I use GET methods I will lose my requirement of not showing user data on the browser URL and if I use POST methods I cannot pass data programmatically on the controller. Maybe I wil have to think in another approach.

Comment: You can still do redirect with GET(PRG pattern). Read the TempData section of the answer i linked above

Comment: So you want to create a workflow with a set amount of stages. When a user has completed stage 1 he can go to stage 2 and revisit s1. If he has completed stage 2, he will go to stage 3 and is able to revisit stage 1 / 2, is that corect?