# Error When trying to Register a User in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Hi I have Faced With a Problem  When Im Trying To Register.
This Is My Code :

```
public ActionResult RegisterButton(Models.Users User)
    {
        using (MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext())
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid == false)
            {
                return View("Register", User);
            }

            else
            {
                db.Users.Add(User);

                db.SaveChanges();
                Session["UserId"] = User.Id;
                //Directory.CreateDirectory(string.Format("~/App_Data/{0}",User.UserName+User.Id.ToString()));
                return RedirectToAction("Profile", "Profile",new { User.Id});
            }
        }
    }
```

And This Is Also My Route Config Code :

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

And I Get This Error :
**The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'UserId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Profile(Int32)' in 'DigiDaroo.Controllers.ProfileController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.**

Please Help:|

Comment: How does your `Profile` action method signature looks like ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you provided, your `RegisterButton` method will return a redirect response to the browser with location header value like this

```
/Profile/Profile/101
```

Where `101` is replaced with the actual ID of the new User record. With the routing configuration you have, your code would not throw that error message if your action method parameter name is `id`. Since you are getting the error message, i assume your action method parameter name is something else. So make sure you are explicitly passing that the routeValue object.

For example, if your action method parameter name is `userId` like this

```
public ActionResult Profile(int userId)
{
    // to do : return something
}
```

your redirect response call should be like this

```
return RedirectToAction("Profile", "Profile",new { userId = User.Id});
```

This will send the location header value for the redirect response as `/Profile/Profile?userId=101` and browser will use this to make the GET request. since we are explicitly passing the `userId` parameter in querystring, your error parameter will be properly filled with the value `101`

Another option is to change your action method parameter name to `id`

```
public ActionResult Profile(int id)
{
    // to do : return something
}
```

Comment: can we Make This Post Request? If We Can Please Post The COde

Comment: Why do you want to make POST request after saving ? It does not make sense. Follow the PRG pattern. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209191/how-do-i-include-a-model-with-a-redirecttoaction/11209320#11209320