# How do you update a viewmodel with radiobutton selected value from ajax call?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, model, radio-button, asp.net-ajax

I'm pretty new regarding frontend, and couldn't find a clear solution to this simple problem.
In a Visual 2017 c# ASP.NET Framework MVC project, for a single page with ONLY ONE SUBMIT button which is already used for updating some string of my model totalInfo, I want to update the integer property ModelltypeForView of my model from the selected value of n radiobuttons.

I learnt I could update my controller model going with an AJAX call, but I can't find the way to update my view model, I must miss something simple but not obvious for a beginner.

Here are the main parts of my MVC.

I am aware of the problems due to the return type of my SettModelltype of my controller, as well as the ajax and foreach loop of my view, so basically: how do I finish this code? Is this problem even fixable without any partial view?

Thank you so much for your time.

```cs
// Model TotalInfoModell.cs

public class TotalInfoModell
{
        public List<Modelltype> Modelltyper { get; set; }
        public int ModelltypeForView { get; set; }
}

public class Modelltype
{
        public int MTIndex { get; set; }
        public string MTName { get; set; }
        public bool MTSelected { get; set; } //? useless?
}

// Controller MainController.cs

static TotalInfoModell _totalInfo;

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Main()
{
    if (_totalInfo == null)
    {
        _totalInfo = new TotalInfoModell();
    }
    return View(_totalInfo);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SettModelltype(TotalInfoModell totalInfoFraView)
{
      _totalInfo.ModelltypeForView = totalInfoFraView.ModelltypeForView;
      for (int i = 0; i < _totalInfo.Modelltyper.Count; i++)
      {
         _totalInfo.Modelltyper[i].MTSelected = (i == _totalInfo.ModelltypeForView);
       }   /// Could be useless

       return RedirectToAction("Main");   //????
}

// View Main.cshtml
@foreach (var modelltype in Model.Modelltyper)
{
      @Html.RadioButtonFor(i => modelltype.MTIndex == Model.ModelltypeForView, modelltype.MTIndex, new { @class = "MTSelected" })   // ????
      @modelltype.MTName<br />
}
...


<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.MTSelected').change(function () {
            var viewModel = {
                    "ModelltypeForView": $('.MTSelected:checked').val(),
                };
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("SettModelltype", "Main")',
                data: viewModel,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert("It didn't work");
                }
            }).done(function (data) {
                alert("Done");
                $('#Id').val(data.ModelltypeForView);   //??? Should return totalInfoModell
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand. Do you want to pass your viewmodel back with the redirect?

If that's the case you can add it as a parameter. [Here is a post that can help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11209320/2599508)

Comment: Hi,
No, this is one of the random parts of the code...
I want to pass my freshly updated model from the controller back to the view with its updated ModelltypeForView value.
That way I can update my radiobuttons on the condition checked = modelltype.MTIndex == Model.ModelltypeForView or sthing like that, since this syntax is wrong.
The problem is once I clicked on the submit button of the view for updating the rest of the model, the radiobuttons are all unchecked. 
I dont know how to pass my values back to the model in the view from an ajax call.

Comment: You can return the viewmodel as json and in the success function of the ajax call set the values in the view: **return Json(_totalInfo.ModelltypeForView)**

Comment: OK, thank you, it gave me a way to lose my thing.
Just a question: I end up retrieving my ModelltypeForView value in the ajax call like this:

success: function (response) {
                    $("#ModelltypeForView").val(response);

but if I don't use model.ModellTypeForView in a textbox or hiddenfor in the view, the value won't be updated. Is it normal?