# How can I filter database results from a Form post?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core-mvc

I am pretty certain my lack of understanding is preventing me form getting it to work.

I currently have a form that will post filtering parameters back to the controller, then it will build up the query. The current queries I build does not seam to actually do anything. At least not when it is separated like this.

From what I have read, something like this should work, but from what I have tested, it does not.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> FilterPost()
{
    var query = _context.Products;
    query = query.OrderBy(m => m.Unit.Name)
         .Include(m => m.Unit)
         .Include(m => m.Attribute);

    foreach (var request in Request.Form)
    {
         var AttributeValue = request.Value;
         var AttributeName = request.Key;
         query = query.Where(m => m.Attribute.Name == AttributeName)
                      .Where(m => m.Value >= int.Parse(AttributeValue));
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

This method is probably pretty butchered with all the testing I have done on it.

I have looked into using ExpressionTrees and DynamicLINQ before. They do seam confusingly interestring and perhaps a bit overkill, maybe? I dont know. Maybe I my brain is just too exhausted to see the obvious answer...

I would appreciate any kind of suggestion for a solution or a hint towards an solution.

Comment: You are not passing any model back to your view. Whatever result is produced by your query remains in the controller. See the overloads of RedirectToAction or this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209191/how-do-i-include-a-model-with-a-redirecttoaction

Comment: You should return the result to be able to get a response.

Comment: "This method is probably pretty butchered with all the testing I have done on it." - then FIX IT. Btw., nice to put together aquery - it is NEVER EXECUTED. You redirect to /Index without any filtering.

Comment: Yeah, it does not post anything back to the index because I am just using breakpoints to see what is happening with the query. One step at a time.

But I will take all of your suggestions and tips, and try to bash it in to my thick skull. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, set breakpoint and inspect what is inside `request`. Moreover, you filter data based on `request` fields, but in each loop iteration you are filtering result more and more, so you have to consider this carefully.

Also, when redirecting to `Index`, you don't pass any data and I think you should pass result of a `query` there, so you can use it and show it there. So I'd take look at overloads of `RedirectToAction` such as `RedirectToAction(String, Object)`. Alternatively, you can take a look at `View` method with similair capabilities as `RedirectToAction`.

Having said that, you shuld pass RESULTS of a query, so you need to get the result of a query, for example, by calling `ToList` method.

Comment: It is a post method because he posts the form back to the controller.

Comment: @TomTom Agree, but it could be done via query string parameters. Post method (as far as I know) should be used for modifyng data, not only for getting it.

Comment: Query string parameters, that's what it's called. I wondered what it was called but it never really appeared in a context where it would click in my head. Something to more deeply look in to. I mostly got suck with the Form Post method because of my lack of technical vocabulary concerning this topic. I thank you for your input.