# passing a view model with RedirectToAction

Tags: c#, web, model-view-controller

I want to pass a view model from one action to another action with the RedirectToAction, however when doing this, I get an error stating that "Object reference not set to an instance of an object", when i have already populated the model with data from the controller, but it is null in the view. I want to pass the data from Login to LoggedIn. I dont want to use query string as this can be easily manipulated by a hacker

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(User account)
{
    using (TestDBEntities db = new TestDBEntities())
    {
        var user = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Email == account.Email && u.Password == account.Password);
        if (user != null)
        {
            Session["USER"] = user.UserID;
            var model = new UserAccountViewModel{UserAccount = user};
            return RedirectToAction("LoggedIn", model);
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError("", "User credentials are invalid");
    }

    return View("Login");
}

public ActionResult LoggedIn(UserAccountViewModel model)
{
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: what does your LoggedIn.cshtml looks like?

Comment: Try this : (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209191/how-do-i-include-a-model-with-a-redirecttoaction)

Answer (score 2):

`RedirectToAction` kicks a 30x back to the browser.  Your view model won't survive that kind of trip.

You could either store your view model in the `TempData` collection, 
Or just call the function you want:  `return mySuperCoolControllerInstance.ActionsAreJustMethods(viewModel)`

in your case it would be:  `return this.LoggedIn(model);`