# How pass data between two controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

in which way I can pass data from one controller to another?

I have this action CheckReservation in HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public readonly ICarRepository _repository;

    public HomeController(ICarRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult CheckReservation(Reservation reservation)
    {
        List<Car> availableCars = _repository.GetAvailableCars.Where(c => c.Location == reservation.PickUpLocation && c.Available);

        return RedirectToAction("List", "Car", availableCars);

    }
}
```

And I have this action List in CarController:

```
public class CarController : Controller
{
    private readonly ICarRepository _repository;

    public CarController(ICarRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult List(List<Car> cars = null)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if(cars == null)
            {
                var carsListViewModel = new CarsListViewModel
                {
                    Cars = _repository.GetAllCars
                };
                return View(carsListViewModel);
            }
            else
            {
                return View(cars);
            }
        }

        return NotFound();

    }

    public IActionResult Detail(int id)
    {
        var car = _repository.GetAllCars.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);

        return View(car);

    }
}
```

I tried on this way but I only getting cars list without any elements.
What is correct way to pass data between controllers?

Edit: Found solution here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209191/how-do-i-include-a-model-with-a-redirecttoaction)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `TempData` to transfer the data.

```
TempData["Key"] = dataObject;
```

And accessing the same `dataObject` in another Controller

```
Object data = TempData["Key"] as Object;
```

You can use tempdata on next request using `Keep()` method also.