# How to redirect to root controller action method from an area controller in .net core mvc application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I need to redirect to root controller action method from an area controller in Asp.Net Core MVC application. I'm trying to use

```
return RedirectToAction("Actionname","ControllerName",modelObject)
```

But this is trying to locate the controller in the area itself, which is not present and I'm getting a 404 error. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below.

`return RedirectToAction("Actionname", "ControllerName", new { area = "" });`

Also you can not pass `modelObject` to `RedirectToAction` as per the [ControllerBase.RedirectToAction Method documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.redirecttoaction?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: what if i need to send the model object?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11209320/9695286 This answer can help your to pass model. Though it is asked for `asp.net mvc` but it also covers `Using TempData to pass model data to a redirect request in Asp.Net Core`.